# How to append elements using a mut ref to a vec which is a slice?

Tags: rust

```
fn main()
{
    let mut a = vec!["1".to_string(), "2".to_string()];
    let r: &mut [String] = &mut a;
    r.push("1".to_string());
}
```

If it's not possible, I would like to understand why it can't be done using the mut ref to the slice.

```
   Compiling Practise v0.1.0 (C:\My Files\Coding\Reading_Material\Rust\Practise)
error[E0599]: no method named `push` found for mutable reference `&mut [String]` in the current scope
 --> src\main.rs:4:7
  |
4 |     r.push("1".to_string());
  |       ^^^^ method not found in `&mut [String]`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
error: could not compile `Practise` due to previous error
```

Comment: Because slices are not growable. `Vec`s are.

Comment: A slice could point to the middle of another slice, or to an array. To grow a data structure you need extra information that slices lack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Vec` contains a pointer, length, and capacity. When pushing a new element to a `Vec`, if `length < capacity`, there is extra space available for the new element. Otherwise, the `Vec` can be reallocated, increasing the capacity to make `length < capacity` (and possibly changing the pointer).

A slice contains just a pointer and a length. Since there is no capacity, it is not possible to know if there is additional capacity available for a new element or to increase the capacity.

So a mutable reference to a slice only allows modifying the existing elements, not adding new elements. Only a mutable reference to the `Vec` can perform modifications that need to know the capacity.